# Set CWD for NPM script that runs a binary

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts, working-directory

I have a super-project that hosts sub-projects and contains common dependencies:

```
super
  node_modules
    .bin
      foo-binary
      foo-binary.exe
    foo
  sub
    node_modules
    package.json
  package.json
```

I need to be able to call `foo` either as `super` NPM script:

*super/package.json*

```
"scripts": {
  "foo": "foo-binary" <-- should run with super/sub/ as CWD
}
```

In this case `foo-binary` runs with `super/` as CWD, while it should run with `super/sub/`. The use of `cd` results in cross-platform problems; `cd sub && ..\\node_modules\\.bin\\foo-binary` with backslashes works on Windows but not *nix OSes, while `cd sub && ../node_modules/.bin/foo-binary` with forward slashes fails on Windows (tested on Windows 7):

> ".." is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Or I need to be able to call `foo` either as `super` NPM script:

*super/sub/package.json*

```
"scripts": {
  "foo": "../node_modules/.bin/foo-binary"
}
```

In this case platform-specific paths fail on Windows, too.

There are several reasons why `sub` cannot have `foo` as its own dependency, one of them is that all sub-projects should consistently use the same `foo` version and not occupy space with multiple `foo` copies.

How can current working directory be set in this case, cross-platform and preferably without adding custom scripts to the project?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-script-os

Comment: @HolgerWill Thanks, I'll keep it in mind but I hope there's a simpler way.

Comment: @RobC I updated the question. What Windows version did you test it with? I tried it in Windows 7 but it's possible that it was fixed in later cmd.exe.

Comment: It was _Vista_ dare I say it ;) Maybe try wrapping the path (in the npm-script) with JSON escaped double quotes i.e. `\"...\"`. For instance: `"foo": "cd sub && \"../node_modules/.bin/foo-binary\""`

Comment: @RobC Thank you, that's it. Consider posting this as an answer if you don't mind. It makes sense that since Windows treats `/` as a delimiter, there's a need for quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the path that is defined in your npm-script with JSON escaped double quotes i.e. `\"...\"`.

For instance:

```json
"scripts": {
  "foo": "cd sub && \"../node_modules/.bin/foo-binary\""
}
```

This will now run successfully cross-platform - via windows `cmd.exe` and *nix `sh`.